# Convert an FeedResponse<Class> into List<Class> in DocumentDB

Tags: c#, linq, json.net, deserialization, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to convert a FeedResponse into List but failing to serialize the string as it throws an error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Lutran.Api.Models.Infinity]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'token', line 1, position 9.

I have used the logic for pagination using the this [link](http://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/08/19/paging-through-query-results-in-azure-documentdb/) and getting the data when returning the entire output object but when im trying to convert it fails.Tried using an ienumerable object but it shows type conversion error.Used a dynamic object but cannot extract ResponseContinuation value from it.

Using Newton Soft to convert the json(deserialize the string)

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collection, options).AsDocumentQuery();

if (query.HasMoreResults)
{
     var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<LeadDataView>();

     objLeadDataView.ResponseContinuation = result.ResponseContinuation;
     objLeadDataView.InfinityDataView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Infinity>>(result.ToString());
     response = objLeadDataView;
}
```

Comment: Your exception message is self explanatory, You can use _Newtonsoft Json_ to parse your json to .net object

Comment: Please post the code following [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RahulSingh checck the code i get that error when i tried using jsonconvert from newtonsoft only

Comment: @SainathNaidu - Yeah that is mentioned in your exception message right? You are passing a collection but you are getting back a single object, try with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Infinity>(result.ToString());` instead.

Comment: @RahulSingh objLeadDataView.InfinityDataView is a List<Infinity> object and i tried removing list but shows error "cannot implicitly convert type "

Comment: @RahulSingh unless there's an implicit conversion between Infinity and InfinityDataView, then it should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InfinityDataView>(result.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out

```
public class LeadDataView
{
    public string ResponseContinuation { get; set; }

    public FeedResponse<Infinity> InfinityDataView { get; set; }
}

if (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Infinity>();

                objLeadDataView.ResponseContinuation = result.ResponseContinuation;
                objLeadDataView.InfinityDataView = result;
                response = objLeadDataView;
            }
```

So the above code sent the continuation token on top and infinity class data below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igUA1.png)